# What is the @ Symbol in a Laravel Spark Vue.js Template?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-spark

In Laravel Spark's template files, you'll occasionally see something like this

```
<span class="help-block" v-show="form.errors.has('name')">
    @{{ form.errors.get('name') }}
</span>
```

That is, a span that's conditionally toggled visible/invisible based on the form's current errors.

I understand this part

```
{{ form.errors.get('name') }}
```

It's a Vue.js template that will display the string returned by `form.errors.get('name')`.  However -- what's the `@` symbol in front of the template for?  I know, as an attribute, [@ is a shorthand for `v-on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html).  However,

```
v-on{{ form.errors.get('name') }}
```

makes even less sense to me, so I'm guessing the `@` symbol does something else here.  Is this a Vue.js thing?  A Laravel Spark thing?  Something else?

Comment: If It's blade file it says laravel to ignore it because It's part of Vue template.
Basically Vue and Laravel Blade use same thing for templating and binding dynamic values and expressions - mustaches `{{  }}`

Comment: @BelminBedak D'oh -- face palm.  I got a bit too wrapped up in Vue and forgot where I was :)  If you want to write that up as an answer I'm happy to up vote and mark as best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because Vue and Laravel Blade use the same syntax for binding dynamic values and expressions.

`@` into the mustaches expression (in blade file) means that Laravel should ignore it so Vue will take care of It.

Note: If you want to use another templating expression for Vue, check delimiters section in docs - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters

Answer (score 1):

`@` symbol its a Laravel thing to inform the Blade rendering engine an expression should remain untouched.  The `@` is used in Laravel blade templates.